# Why Am I Getting No such element found error in Appium+ Flutter Automation code?

Tags: flutter, automation, appium, nosuchelementexception

I am new to flutter automation with appium. I have followed examples in internet. But it is giving me no such element found error. Basically I am trying to identify elements with ValueKey, Sementiclabel. This is the code that I was trying to execute automation.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("noReset", true);
    capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "Appium");
    capabilities.setCapability("app", "E:\\app-debug.apk");
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub");
    AndroidDriver<WebElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(url, capabilities);

    FlutterFinder find = new FlutterFinder(driver);
    FlutterElement e = find.bySemanticsLabel("text");
    e.getText();
    System.out.println(value);
```

These are the dependencies which is used in my pom.xml file.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.ashwithpoojary98</groupId>
    <artifactId>appium_flutterfinder_java</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I added dev dependencies in my app's source code as follows in the pubspec.yaml

```yaml
dev_dependencies:
    test: any
    flutter_test:
        sdk: flutter
    flutter_driver:
        sdk: flutter
```

In main.dart file code is also changed like this.

```
import 'package:flutter_driver/driver_extension.dart';
void main() {
    enableFlutterDriverExtension();
    runApp(const MyApp());
```

This is the error message I was getting

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: The element identified by 'eyJpc1JlZ0V4cCI6ImZhbHNlIiwibGFiZWwiOiJ0ZXh0IiwiZmluZGVyVHlwZSI6IkJ5U2VtYW50aWNzTGFiZWwifQ==' is not present in the cache or has expired. Try to find it again (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 191 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'
System info: host: 'Isuru', ip: '192.168.137.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '19.0.1'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
```

Answer (score 0):

We have invalide automationName by

```
  capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "Appium");
```

Use the following instead of:

1. Uiautomator2
2. Flutter